# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{-k}{k+n \choose k}=2^n$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, induction, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I am trying to show that $$\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{-k}{k+n \choose k}=2^n.$$

I try $n=0$:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^0 2^{-k}{k+n \choose k}=2^0{0 \choose 0}=1=2^0,
$$
and $n=1$:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^1 2^{-k}{k+n \choose k}=1+ 2^{-1}{1+1 \choose 1}=1+\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2=1+1=2^1,
$$
so far I have a solid understanding of how this is working. It seems like induction might be a good way to go about finishing this, but I can't quite see how to make the connection of how assuming $n$ is true implies $n+1$ is true. Any advice?

Or alternatively, there may be a simple combinatorial proof that does not rely on induction, and instead utilizes a clever rearrangement. (I have rather poor intuition of these types of proofs, so that's why I tend to prefer induction, where there are clear steps towards a solution.)

Comment: Or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1973495/573047).

Comment: If you want to ask a new question, please create a new question instead of editing this one.